# Can't access localhost on Sequel Pro

Tags: macos-big-sur, sequelpro

i've just updated to big sur
and i'm using this tutorial to setup localhost in mac

https://websitebeaver.com/set-up-localhost-on-macos-high-sierra-apache-mysql-and-php-7-with-sslhttps

but then i got caught on error in sequel pro [image]

what can i do to make localhost work on sequel pro?